# RenderTargetBitmap doesn't seem to render my rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, rendertargetbitmap

I have the following code:

```
        LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
        linGrBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0,0);
        linGrBrush.EndPoint = new Point(1, 0);
        linGrBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 0.0));
        linGrBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 0.5));
        linGrBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.White, 1.0));

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Width = 1000;
        rect.Height = 1;
        rect.Fill = linGrBrush;
        rect.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1000));
        rect.Measure(new Size(1000, 1));
```

If I do

```
 myGrid.Children.Add(rect);
```

Then the gradient is drawn fine on the window.

I want to use this gradient for an intensity map somewhere else, so I need to get the pixels out of it. To do this, I understand I can convert it to a bitmap, using `RenderTargetBitmap`. Here's the next part of the code:

```
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            1000,1,72,72,
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(rect);

        Image myImage = new Image();
        myImage.Source = bmp;
```

To test this, I do:

```
myGrid.Children.Add(myImage);
```

But nothing appears on the window. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Arrange` has to be called after `Measure`, and the `Rect` values should be passed correctly.

Instead of

```
rect.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1000)); // wrong width and height
rect.Measure(new Size(1000, 1));
```

you should do

```
var rect = new Rectangle { Fill = linGrBrush };
var size = new Size(1000, 1);
rect.Measure(size);
rect.Arrange(new Rect(size));

var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(1000, 1, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(rect);
```